# Why I can't use BlocksHelper from custom plugin?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I create "BlocksHelper" in my custom plugin, but I can't use it without fatal errors. What is wrong?

plugin/myPlugin/src/View/Helper/BlocksHelper.php:

```
namespace myPlugin\View\Helper;
use Cake\View\Helper;

class BlockHelper extends Helper{
}
```

bootstrap.php:

```
...
Plugin::load(myPlugin, ['autoload' => true]);
```

View/AppView.php:

```
class AppView extends View
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadHelper('myPlugin.Blocks');
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP! Also show/describe the corresponding context, ie show/highlight the code that actually triggers the error, and please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks! Often problems even solve themselves when collecting these information.

Comment: Why is your class called `BlockHelper` when the file name is `BlocksHelper`?